# PHP GnuPG - Signing message fails with passphrase

Tags: php, pgp

According to [PHP GnuPG - Signing message fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378087/php-gnupg-signing-message-fails)
I have the same problem:
If I remove the passphrase from an existing Key it did not work.
With a new key generate without passphrase it will work.
But I must use the old key. So how I can solve it?

Comment: "It did not work" is pretty broad. What does that mean?

Comment: When I attempt to sign the message using gnupg_sign($res, "my message"), I get the following error and gnupg_sign returns false:

gnupg_sign(): data signing failed

Comment: Please add all clarification and your debugging attempts to the question by editing it

Comment: What do you think that I do? I link to another question and say that my problem is the same. So what new information do you need? Or did you response just do add some text? 
:-(